# Gnuradio: How to Detect a FFT Plot's Peak?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am using a hackRF connected to Gnuradio to collect the signal that comes from a one-key remote control. I only need to have a estimation of the distance between the remote control and my receiver (HackRF).

I have designed the following grc file that filters my area of interest. I need to find the peak value (the highest value of the FFT plot that is provided by FFT sink) and if that value is higher than a threshold (e.g., -50db), I will need to write that value to a file (e.g, a text file).

[image]

To sum up, I want to have a output file that includes all peak values of FFT that are greater than a threshold. For example, in the attached picture, such value is around -22db.

[image]

Comment: Pass the time domain signal through an fft block and into a custom out of tree module sink that reads the samples and compares them to a threshold.

Answer (score 1):

In your flow graph, if you're trying to avoid the DC offset of the HackRF, then the baseband frequency of the FFT sink should be set to 917MHz-340kHz.

You could use rtl_power with a rtl dongle (calibrated to a know frequency in the 900 MHz band) which would output a CSV file.

Comment: That DC is a real pain ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy in GNU Radio. The flowgraph below may be a good starting point. You have to take care the parameters of the `Log Power FFT block`, however. Note that the flowgraph will store 0, for samples below threshold which is not so right. If you to store only the values above the threshold you have two choices.

1. You use the `Valve` and `Signal Probe` block properly, but depending the sampling rate may affect your performance.
2. You implement a custom block that outputs samples only when the trigger is on.
   [image: flowgraph]

Good luck!

Comment: I built this exact graph, with a scope sink instead of file sink, and I don't get any samples coming out of the max.  I tried a bunch of things but it seems like the max block has some issues in 3.7.9 on Ubuntu 16.04.2.  Has anybody else seen this?

Comment: @portforwardpodcast Are you sure? Perhaps they are all zeros.